# Possible for left hand infinite limit with right hand 0

Tags: calculus

Is it possible for a function to have a limit from the left be infinite and the limit from the right be zero if both limits are approaching the same number?
I am inclined to say yes, but I am not sure, and is there an equation I could use to demonstrate this?

Comment: See the question linked by @EpsilonDelta; there is an answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-\frac 1x \,\,\,\,\, \text{if $x\le 0$}\\
0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{      otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The limit from the left equals infinity while the one from the right equals 0.

EDIT: I just looked at the duplicate question and it seemed that Brian M Scott posted the same answer as me.